# My program just reads half an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I need my program to read an array from txt. file, It apperantly does, but when I paid attention to the numbers, I discovered that only half array is correct, the rest are random. 
Furthermore, if I read 2 diferent arrays, the random numbers are the same.

There is the code:

```
    //List of Biblio. 
#include <cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


FILE *fp;

//Functiotns declaration.

//
void dimensions(int &,int &,int &);
//


void rTime (int** ,int,int,int &); // The first int, it's an Array! 
//
void rTimeprint (int** ,int,int,int);
//



void spt (int**,vector<int> & ,int,int); // The first int it's an Array!
//
int block (int, int,int, int,int,int);
//
int neh (int,int,int,int,int,int,int);
//
static int swap (int, int,int,int,int,int,int,int,double,double,float);
//
//A inserta, hi ha una matriu (1st int) i vector (3rd int)
static int inserta (int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int, double,double,float );
//
static int sa (double,double,float);



  //Array varaibles;
  int column, row, nombreProblemes; 


int main() { 

// Open the file where's the array;

fp = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");


dimensions(column, row, nombreProblemes);            

// Create the Array:

int *matriuTemps[column];

for (int i= 0; i<column;i++){
     matriuTemps[i] = new int [row];
}//end of loop Array[][] creator




// Function read time (array)

rTime(matriuTemps, column, row,problema);

//Function print the Array
rTimePrint(matriuTemps, column,row,problema);


}//End of main
```

And there is the function rTime:

```
void rTime(int *matriuTemps [],int column, int row, int &Problema){

  fscanf(fp, "%d",&Problema);

   for (int i= 0; i<row; i++){//Outter loop (row)

       for (int j=0; j<column;j++){//inner loop (column))

           matriuTemps[i][j]=0;

           fscanf(fp,"%d",&matriuTemps [i][j]);

          }//inner loop         
   }//outer loop
```

If it is more infor for you i put the function which prints the array:

```
void rTimeprint (int *matriuTemps[20] ,int column,int row,int problema){

cout<<"\nAquest és la matriu de temps del problema: "<< problema <<endl<<endl;

for (int i= 0; i<row; i++){//Outter loop (row)

   for (int j=0; j<column;j++){//inner loop (column))

       cout<< matriuTemps[i][j]<<"\t";

   }//inner loop
   cout << endl; 

  }//outer loop
}
```

And finally the Output: (i mark with x x, the column here the values start to be random, From there to the right are all random)
first Array

```
                                 x
                                 x
54  83  15  71  77  36  53  38  27  87  76  91  14  29  12  77  32  87  68  94  
79  3   11  99  56  70  99  60  16  89  49  15  89  45  60  23  66  58  31  68  
16  89  49  15  89  45  60  23  66  58  31  68  78  91  13  59  58  56  20  85  
66  58  31  68  78  91  13  59  58  56  20  85  53  35  53  41  69  13  86  72  
58  56  20  85  53  35  53  41  69  13  86  72  8   49  47  87  58  18  68  28
```

Second Array:

```
                                     x
                                     x   
    0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0   0  87  76  91  14  29  12   77 32  87  68  94  
    45  33  11  99  56  0   87  60  16  89  49  15  89  45  60  23  66  58  31  68  
    12  89  40  15  89  45  60  23  66  58  31  68  78  91  13  59  58  56  20  85  
    46  57  1   68  78  95  78  53  58  56  20  85  53  35  53  41  15  13  86  72  
    52  56  20  95  3   15  78  42  15  13  86  72  8   49  47  87  58  18  68  28
```

Comment: You know you can name parameters, right ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have got your `row` and `column` dimensions mixed up - this part:

```
int *matriuTemps[column];

for (int i= 0; i<column;i++){
     matriuTemps[i] = new int [row];
}
```

should be:

```
int *matriuTemps[row];           // allocate `row` rows

for (int i= 0; i<row;i++){       // for each row
     matriuTemps[i] = new int [column];
}                                // allocate `column` elements
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `main` function`you declare`matriuTemps`to be an array of`column`elements, each element being a pointer to`int`.

But in in e.g. `rTime` you treat the array as an array of *`row`* elements, each element being an array of `column` integers. So you mix up the indexes, and unless both `row` and `column` are equal you will have problems.

---

Also note that C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), making your definition of `matriuTemps` not proper C++.

Instead, if you want dynamic arrays, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Maybe something like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matriuTemps(column, std::vector<int>(row));
```

The above line defined `matriuTemps` to be a vector or vectors of integers, and set the size of both "dimensions".